# Why the indicator for https condition at left side of URL bar alerted in yellow

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, https

Why the indicator for https condition at left side of URL bar alerted in yellow

I would like to know why the indicator for https condition at left side of URL bar alerted in yellow even when I just read through tweets on main page tab(Home) and click other connected person page just read through and then return to my home tab. It happened after several mins and It happened only once. Even I tried to do the same operation again, It did not happen.

Before that, I confirmed It was green icon and there were very strange things happened even I saw the tweet on main page(home) and close my session by clicking close button of Chrome. Then I accessed to Twitter.com by HTTPS with green indicator, The top view was not "Home" tab where you can see recommendation. It was "Connect" tab. Somehow, It's recovered I can see Home tab as default. It's very strange things happened on me.

[image]

*** Question: ***

1. What kind of attack I'm facing?
2. How can I prevent?
3. How can I identify this type of failure?

*** FYI: ***

Lock icon green https:

Google Chrome has successfully Established a secure connection with the site. Look for this icon and make sure the URL has the correct domain, if you're required to log in to the site or enter sensitive information on the page. If a site uses an Extended Validation SSL (EV-SSL) certificate, the organization's name also appears next to the icon in green text.
alert icon yellow https:

The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has Detected Insecure content on the page. Be careful if you're entering sensitive information on this page. Insecure content can Provide a loophole for someone to change the look of the page.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en&ref_topic=14666

Comment: We need more information about the certificate

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/638773/http-redirect-to-https-sometimes-leads-to-this-page-contains-other-resources-wh http://superuser.com/questions/368261/chrome-says-this-page-contains-some-resources-that-are-not-secure-in-all-https

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yeah, I forgot to check it but I just take a screen shot of it's yellow. But Not useful to investigate. next time I will do it.

Comment: Some times your timeline will include images includes from non-HTTPS sites, turning the icon yellow

Comment: Thank you. I usually use Twitter function to upload image from my desktop. and I tried to do the operation contains clicking the favorite contents of Wired also, It was not reproduced. Anyway, I will check the certificate next time.